# How do I get Tornadus?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

My brother really wants Tornadus, but he doesn't know how to get it. How can you catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site provides some straightforward instructions](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-black-white/catching-tornadus-or-thundurus/)

> In previous pokémon games, you could see roaming legendaries on the map. But in Pokémon Black and White, you can't see them on the map. Instead, the electronic bulletin boards in the route houses might mention "a very unusual storm" in a particular route. If you go to that route and there is a huge rainstorm, then that means that a random encounter in the grass might be an encounter with Tornadus/Thundurus.
>
> Since you won't be able to chase Tornadus or Thundurus around because they don't show up on the map, just go into and out of a route house until the route has a huge rainstorm in it. Then you can go around in the grass to try to encounter Tornadus or Thundurus.

The site includes more detail on how to battle and catch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Blk2/Wht2 then you have to get Tornadus through the 3DS Dream Radar.